# Accessing the Original Question After Edit Submission on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

I have recently submitted an edit to a question on **Stack Overflow**. My intention was to review the original question (before the edit was accepted or rejected) for verification purposes. However, I am currently unable to access the original question.

Is there a method or feature available that allows access to the original question after submitting an edit, or is this perhaps a technical issue that needs addressing?

I attempted to find relevant information on this matter, but I was unable to locate any specific results.

Comment: Just right click the link to the question, e.g. its title, and choose "open link in incognito window", i.e. view the question when not logged in.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Thanks, it worked and also helped a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392767/accessing-the-original-question-after-edit-submission-on-stack-overflow#comment1313482_392767) made under the question:

> Just right click the link to the question, e.g. its title, and choose
> "open link in incognito window", i.e. view the question when not
> logged in.

And this indeed solved my issue.